# Convert hh:mm:ss.ms to millisecond in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, data-conversion, date-arithmetic

I have doubt. how to convert hh:mm:ss.ms to millisecond in Postgres.

For example `01:25:43.81` to `5143810`

Comment: And I need vice versa too. milliseconds to hh:mm:ss.ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
extract(epoch from '01:25:43.81'::time) * 1000
```

The other way around:

```
'00:00:00'::time + 5143810/1000.0 * interval '1' second
```